# How to unset a property in a FactoryBot trait?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In my model, I have a property **foo** that have a default value.

I want to write a test related with the default value of **foo**, but my FactoryBot is setting its as nil (and overriding the default value).

If I remove **foo** from the factory bot it will break some other tests. So I would like to use something like a ***trait*** to create a case where **foo** is not net, but I didn't find any way to unset the property.

Is there some way to unset a property in FactoryBot?

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :my_model do
    foo { 'abc' }
    bar { 'abc' }

    trait(:foo_not_set) do
      # magic to unset foo
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So in default case you want it to be set to default and in trait - to nil?

Comment: The opposite nil for default case and default for trait. (I know that is confused but the default rule is something new )

Comment: Well, tough case :)

Comment: I would like to avoid refactor the test, but if there is no other way... Here we go!

Comment: Create a factory without foo and create a trait with foo. This way, test data has to be changed, not the test case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can play around with virtual attributes with transient block:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :my_model do
    bar { 'abc' }

    transient do
      default_values true
    end

    before(:create) do |my_model, evaluator|
      if evaluator.default_values?
        foo { 'abc' }
      end
    end

    trait(:foo_not_set) do
      transient do
        default_values { false }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Using transient values did not work for me when the factory class was just a Hash, i.e. the trait would be `nil` when I just wanted a hash without that key altogether. What worked best for me was using a nested factory and setting what you might refer to as the "default" factory to be the nested one... a slightly backwards approach but works just the same:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :my_hash_without_foo do
    bar { 'abc' }

    factory :my_hash do
      foo { 'abc' }
    end
  end
end
```